# Google Docs upload works on some accounts but not others

Tags: google-docs-api

I have written a client in C to upload files to Google Docs, I get an authentication token, and use it for the upload. However, I have 4 Google accounts, the upload worked on 2 accounts, but not the other 2. And now, it only works on one account.

On authentication, all accounts behave the same, and ClientLogin issues an "Auth=xxx" token. I use the token 100% successfully on one Google account, it used to work on another, and has never worked on the other 2.

The only error is "HTTP/1.1 401 Token invalid".

One account used to work, and now does not, which does not make much sense. The ClientLogin calls never seem to ask for a CAPTCHA.

Currently I can't invest the time to move to the Drive API, and that may present the same issues anyway.

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Garry

Answer (score 0):

Try them individually first, if this works you can start combining untill all 4 works,
doing it step by step is the way to succes, I can't help you with programming code, according to the fact that I'm just a noobie :) tho I thought myself PHP by just doing it step by step, if you got 1 done, then it's just copy/paste and change abit :)

Goodluck tho :)

Answer (score 0):

You should move your code away from ClientLogin and use OAuth 2.0 instead. You didn't mention what language your script uses but Google has some samples for performing OAuth 2.0 at:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20

and

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/

Jay